# Does the RavenDB compresion bundle provide benefits with many small documents?

Tags: ravendb

I am trying to better understand how RavenDB uses disk space.

My application has many small documents (approximately 140 bytes each).  Presently, there are around 81,000 documents which would give a total data size of around 11MB. However, the size of the database is just over 70MB.

- Is most of the actual space being used by indexes?
- I had read somewhere else that there may be a minimum overhead of around 600 bytes per document.  This would consume around 49MB, which is more in the ballpark of the actual use I am seeing.

Would using the compression bundle provide much benefit in this scenario (many small documents), or is it targeted towards helping reduce the size of databases with very large documents?

Comment: Did my answer below solve it for you?

Comment: See my own answer below. Your guess about the indexes being the main use of disk space turned out to not be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done some further testing on my own and determined, in answer to my own question, that:

- Indexes are not the main consumer of disk space in my scenario.  In this case, indexes represent < 25% of the disk space used.
- Adding the compression bundle for a database with a large number of small documents does not really reduce the total amount of disk space used.  This is likely due to some minimum data overhead that each document requires.  Compression would benefit documents that are very large.

Answer (score 0):

> Is most of the actual space being used by indexes?

Yes, that's likely. Remember that Raven creates indexes for different queries you make. You can fire up Raven Studio to see what indexes it's created for you:

[image]

> Would using the compression bundle provide much benefit in this
>   scenario (many small documents), or is it targeted towards helping
>   reduce the size of databases with very large documents?

Probably wouldn't benefit your scenario of small documents. The compression bundle works on individual documents, not on indexes. But it might be worth trying to see what results you get.

Bigger question: since hard drive space is cheap and only getting cheaper, and 70MB is a spec on the map, why are you concerned about hard drive space? Databases often trade disk space for speed (e.g. multiple indexes, like Raven), and this is usually a good trade off for most apps.

Comment: Drive space is not "cheap" when using a cloud-based RavenDB provider.

Comment: I agree RavenHQ needs to allow more disk space. Still 70MB fits into the $10/month plan on RavenHQ. That's pretty cheap.

Comment: My data is growing at 1-2 MB per day.  This was a forward looking question.